# Angular 4 Custom Router Navigation

Tags: angular, navigation, router, browser-history

Lets say I navigate from page A --> B --> C

How can I remove page B from the navigation history so that when when I am on page C and press browser back it goes to page A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try skipLocationChange.

```
// Navigate silently to /view (Component B)
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

That navigates without pushing its state into history.

The docs for this is here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html#!#skipLocationChange-anchor

Comment: Thanks Deborah! This is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Angular expose a public API to do it right now but if your app uses only a browser platform you can probably do it

```
  window.history.go(-2);
```